# Install 32 bit JRE on 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 for Nokia SDK 2.0

Tags: 12.04, java, 32-bit, nokia

I have successfully install `java` for my `ubuntu` through terminal but in mobile project want to include `Nokia SDK 2.0` but this Platform is not able to run without 32bit jre.

```
Error
```

The SDK could not locate a java runtime enviroment (JRE).You must install JRE6 to run this SDK.

```
Done
```

Then I have download 32 Bit jre form Oracle and install it into a folder but i understant where to move this folder OR set the path for 32 bit java.
if anyone knows about it please help.

As if i check java from terminal

```
java -d32 -version
```

This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM.
Please install the desired version.